# New to git, have file but can't do simple git add

Tags: git

This should be a relatively simple thing but I can't work it out and online searches are not proving fruitful.

- I am learning git from scratch, following a tutorial online and have created a file called `README1.txt`
- I have used `git status` to [see that the file is untracked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DaUP.jpg) and that I would like to track that file.
- I have typed: `git add README1.txt` and [received an error that normally suggests the file doesn't exist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nv1HO.jpg).

**EDIT**:

Thank you for responses, I just had success trying: `git add *` and also putting in single quotation marks as suggested in one of the answers by the helpful community member.

Comment: git add US/README1.txt

Comment: FYI: It's generally easier for everyone on here if you just copy and paste the text from the terminal, rather than posting screenshots.

Comment: Please read a book for Git and for your terminal. This is a really basic question you are asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're providing the wrong path to the `git add` command.
Isn't it U5 or Hyperbowl U5 the folder that contains the file?

Try with `git add 'Hyperbowl U5/README1.txt'`

As in sammms answer, I'd suggest you to avoid to name folders with blank spaces.

Comment: Use quotes for paths with spaces.

Comment: The folder that contains the file is HyperBowl U5.  I have tried to type the full file name including the folder HyperBowl U5 and also not including that

Comment: That was what helped thank you!
Sorry to the community that I didn't ask the question the way that is standardised.  First question here, and won't be my last
I am learning in a variety of ways and Poke, if you have any suggestions for worthwhile books to read please do send them over, today I was using: https://git-scm.com/book/id/v2/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository and got stuck when it wasn't working.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the full file path after the `git add` command.  I.e.

```
git add HyperBowl\ u5/README.txt
```

The backslash is to escape the empty space in your file path, so git doesn't get confused and think those are separate commands.  Avoid having blank spaces in your file paths, use snake_case or CamelCase instead.  For instance, you could name this directory `HyperBowl_u5` and that would be a bit better.

Also, since you only have one file you are trying to add, you could just use the git 'add all' command, i.e. `git add --all` or `git add -A` or `git add .` (that's a period on the end).  Any of those should get you what you want.

Answer (score -1):

Use `git add .`

`git add .` lets you stage your commit in pieces. That's not always necessary if you're committing in properly sized chunks but some times it's inevitable. It also makes it possible to preview a commit. When you use `git add .`  all the files are checked in to your local index, which is separate from your working directory.

The important point about `git add .` is that it looks at the working tree and adds all those paths to the staged changes if they are either changed or are new and not ignored, it does not stage any 'rm' actions.